# How can I configure the middleware to only redirect for a 404 status code

Tags: asp.net-core-3.1

I would like to redirect to a specific page when a 404 is encountered.

I've tried several tutorials and the StatusCodePages and nothing is working.

Does anyone have an example for Core 3.1 that only redirects for a 404 and not all status codes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a couple of options, they should both work in .Net Core. Add this to the web.config file:

```xml
<customErrors mode="Off">
     <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/errorPages/PageNotFound.aspx" />
</customErrors>
```

Or you can just add your own middleware in Startup.cs instead of using the diagnostics package:

```cs
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            if(context.Response.Status == 404)
            {
                // return page
            }
            else
            {
                await next.Invoke();
            }
            // loggin
        });
```

Comment: Could you provide an example please?

Answer (score 0):

It's easy.

```cs
app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/Home/Error/{0}");
```

For this example, in your Home Controller, create a method called Error that takes an integer.

```cs
[ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
[Route("Home/Error/{statusCode}")]
public IActionResult Error(int statusCode)
{
    var error = new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier };
    // Error caused by something other than a 404 should not be processed here.
    if (statusCode != 404)
    {
        return View(error);
    }

    // Logic that handles 404 errors goes here.
}
```

Now, all exceptions will route to this method, but by checking the status code you can have some specific logic for your 404 error.

Comment: Would this also replace `app.UseExceptionHandler()`?

Comment: I'm still not able to get it to work. I have `app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/Error?statusCode={0}");` in my startup and an ErrorController with an Index GET action that matches your example and it's not hitting a breakpoint inside that action. I have removed the route and hitting the url `/error?code=404` manually works, hitting a random url throws the standard blank page.